# A field extension of degree 2 is a Normal Extension.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

> Let $L$ be a field and $K$ be an extension of $L$ such that $[K:L]=2$.
>   Prove that $K$ is a normal extension.

What I have tried : Let $ f(x)$ be any irreducible polynomial in $L[x] $ having a root $\alpha$ in $K$ and let $\beta$ be another root. Then I have to show $\beta \in K$. I already  have $L(\alpha)=K$, but now how to show $\beta\in K??$ 
Any hints?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since $\alpha \in K$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $f \in L[X]$, then $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$. The degree $d$ of $\alpha$ over $L$ is $≤2$, because $[K : L]=2$.

1. If $d=1$, what can you conclude?
2. If $d=2$, write $f(X)=X^2+aX+b=(X-\alpha)(X-\beta)$. What are the relations between $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

> If $d=1$, then $f(X)=X-\alpha$ so that $\beta=\alpha \in K$. If $d=2$, then $X^2+aX+b=X^2-(\alpha+\beta)X+\alpha\beta$ so that $-a=\alpha+\beta$, or $\beta = -a-\alpha \in K$, since $a \in L \subset K$.

Comment: why is $d\leq2??$

Comment: $d$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial $f$. If you had $d>2$, say $d=4$, then the 4 elements $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3 \in K$ would be linearly independent over $L$. But this is impossible since $[K:L]=2$ : every linearly independent set must have at most $2$ elements.

Comment: since $K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\simeq{K(\alpha)}$  and degree of $K(\alpha)$ is 2 over $K$.so is of left hand side.hence $d$ is 2. is it right ??

Comment: Your isomorphism is right. But $\alpha \in K$, so $K(\alpha) = K$ is of degree $1$ over $K$. But $L(\alpha)$ is of degree $d$ over $L$. You could have $d=1$ (think to the case $\alpha \in L$, for instance), or $d=2$.

Comment: Basically, what you have is a "tower" of extensions : $$L \subset L(\alpha) \subset K.$$ The extension $K/L$ has degree $2$ by hypothesis, the extension $L(\alpha)/L$ has degree $d$ by definition,  and $d ≤ 2$.

Comment: Do we need any assumption on the characteristic of L?

Comment: @TheTralfamadorian : no.

Comment: @TheTralfamadorian I think you may be pointing at what's discussed in chapter 13, page 522 of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition, namely that if $L$ is a field of characteristic not equal to $2$, then every extension $K$ of $L$ is of the form $K(\sqrt{D})$ where $D \in K$ is not a square in $L$ (i.e. there is no $y \in L$ such that $y^2 = D$).